Azure DevOps REST API documentation redirection
On REST API doc URL
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP
When I am selecting Azure DevOps Server 2022 from the dropdown I am getting redirected to REST API 7.1. The above endpoint does not exists for On-Prem server since I am getting a "Page not found" when I am invoking Invoke-RestMethod. Why the redirection, when there is clearly a difference between the endpoint versions?

This is because it is not available for an on-prem version. You may check the full list for 7.1:

For 2022:

